# Override Goup Price not working

Tags: magento-1.7, price, overrides, group-price

I've created two product custom attribute to let admin se a starting and ending date for all group price, to let magento calculate correctly the group price only inside the date rage I've override the function getGroupPrice($product) inside the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price like follow:

```
public function getGroupPrice($product)
    {

        $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');

        if (is_null($groupPrices)) {
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('group_price');
            if ($attribute) {
                $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
                $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
            }
        }

        if (is_null($groupPrices) || !is_array($groupPrices)) {
            return $product->getPrice();
        }

        $customerGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);

        $matchedPrice = $product->getPrice();

        // retrive group price data range 
        $group_price_from = $product->getData('group_price_from');
        $group_price_to = $product->getData('group_price_to');
        $paymentDate = date('Y-m-d');
        $paymentDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($paymentDate));


        foreach ($groupPrices as $groupPrice) {
            if ($groupPrice['cust_group'] == $customerGroup && $groupPrice['website_price'] < $matchedPrice) {
                if (($paymentDate > $group_price_from) && (($paymentDate < $group_price_to)||($group_price_to == null)))
            {
                $matchedPrice = $groupPrice['website_price'];
            };
                break;
            }
        }

        return $matchedPrice;
    }
```

Now it work greatly inside the product page so that group price is applied ONLY inside the date range... but it doesn't work in all other position: in cart, inside category page and listing product new... they are displayng the gruop price independently of the data range...

Probably I've missed something ore changed the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to get the product collection whenever retrieved and modify the data. To do so you have to use an observer.

etc/config.xml

```
...
<global>
....
 <events>
  ....
   <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
      <observers>
        <[your_module]>
           <class>[your_module]/observer</class>
           <method>collectionLoadAfter</method>
        </[your_module]>
     </observers>
  </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
 ...
 </events>
....
</global>
```

and then in your Model/observer.php add

```
public function collectionLoadAfter($observer)
{
  foreach($observer->getCollection() as $_item) {
     // $original_price = $_item->getData('price');//to get the original price

     //do your logic here
     $price = 100;//set your custom price 

     $_item->setPrice($price);//this will update the collection

     return $this;
}
```

Note: dont forget to replace [your_module] by your module name.

Now go to the front end and check the price.